# Similarity score between 2 nested lists of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 nested lists and I want to compare all of the nested lists in one list with all of the nested lists in the other.

Example Data:

```
list1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'p'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
list2 = [['g', 'a', 'c'], ['d', 'h', 'b'], ['e', 'f', 'x', 't', 'q']]
```

For the comparison I want to compare each nested list from one list to each nested list in the other list. The comparison score would be calculated by:

```
number of overlaps / length of the longer sublist
```

For the first nested list in list1 the scores with list2 would then be:

```
2/4 -> 0.5
1/4 -> 0.25
1/5 -> 0.2
```

It seems like the best way to do this would then be to create a matrix but I'm not sure if that is the best option or how to calculate the score.

I tried calculating the scores like this but the numbers didn't make sense:

```
overlaps = []
for sublist in list1:
    for sublist2 in list2:
        comb_list = sublist + sublist2
        num_overlap = len(set(comb_list))
        num_long = max(len(sublist), len(sublist2))
        overlap = num_overlap/num_long
        overlaps.append(overlap)
```

Comment: Just a heads up: "overlap" makes it sound like you're comparing element-wise as opposed to just looking for common elements. How exactly do you envision creating a matrix? Surely you don't mean creating a matrix from the lists themselves, as they are of uneven lengths...

Comment: Why the last one is 1/5? there is no match. Also, can the list contain repeated elements like `['a','a','b','c']` ?

Comment: @blorgon Sorry for the overlap confusion, overlap was the word used in the project I'm working on and in this case was defined as 'clusters with the biggest overlap (intersection)' so that is what is meant by it in this case. What you had in the second one is the idea of how I went about implementing it based on that definition but my results were showing values beteween 1 and 2, but I thought it should be between 0 and 1 since at best they would have 100% overlap?

Comment: @kr419 see my answer for explanation. Long story short, you weren't calculating the intersection correctly.

Comment: Why divided by the length of the longer sublist? If you make that term the length of the union of the sets you have the well-trodden Jaccard Similarity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

So the issue with your original approach was that you were calculating the length of `set(sublist1 + sublist2)` but what you wanted was the length of `set(sublist1) & set(sublist2)` or the length of the set intersection:

```py
A = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'p'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
B = [['g', 'a', 'c'], ['d', 'h', 'b'], ['e', 'f', 'x', 't', 'q']]

overlaps = []
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        num_overlap = len(set(a) & set(b))
        num_long = max(len(a), len(b))
        overlaps.append(num_overlap / num_long)
```

Output:

```py
[0.5, 0.25, 0.2, 0.0, 0.25, 0.4, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0]
```

### Comprehension version

Since SO likes comprehensions so much:

```py
overlaps = [len(set(a) & set(b)) / max(len(a), len(b)) for a in A for b in B]
```

### What went wrong in original approach

For a quick example of why your original approach didn't work using the first two comparisons:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x']
>>> b = ['g', 'a', 'c']
>>> comb_list = a + b
>>> comb_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'g', 'a', 'c']
>>> set(comb_list)
{'c', 'g', 'a', 'x', 'b'}
```

### Workaround for original approach

```py
>>> len(comb_list) - len(set(comb_list))
2
```

But that's more work than what I propose in my solution above.

### Dictionary version

Since a list of scores without context might be difficult to interpret, let's use a dictionary:

```py
scores = {}

for i, a in enumerate(A, 1):
    for j, b in enumerate(B, 1):
        num_overlap = len(set(a) & set(b))
        num_long = max(len(a), len(b))
        scores[f"a{i}b{j}"] = num_overlap / num_long

for key, val in scores.items():
    print(f"{key}: {val}")
```

Output:

```py
a1b1: 0.5
a1b2: 0.25
a1b3: 0.2
a2b1: 0.0
a2b2: 0.25
a2b3: 0.4
a3b1: 0.3333333333333333
a3b2: 0.3333333333333333
a3b3: 0.0
```